# how do i delay rendering of a page until my data is available?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have an issue where my page is trying to render before the data is available. I have async awaits in place, however, the page gets an error saying data is undefined. When I comment out my page elements and check react dev tools I can see the data object in full, so I know the data request is working.

I need to put in a check for the data and if present then render but as a new developer I am not sure how to implement this in my code.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { getDoc, doc } from "firebase/firestore";
import { db } from "../api/auth/firebase/config";

import Head from "next/head";
import ArtistHeader from "../../components/ArtistHeader";
import UploadButton from "../../components/UploadButton";
import styles from "../../styles/artistPage.module.css";

export default function Artist() {
  const { data: session, status, loading } = useSession();
  const [artist, setArtist] = useState();
  const router = useRouter();
  const artistId = router.query.artistId;

  const fetchArtist = async () => {
    const artistRef = doc(db, "users", `${artistId}`);
    const docSnap = await getDoc(artistRef);
    setArtist(docSnap.data());
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!router.isReady) return;
    console.log(artistId);
    if (status === "unauthenticated") {
      router.push("/auth/signin");
    }
    fetchArtist();
  }, [status, loading, router]);

  return (
    <section className={styles.wrapper}>
      <Head>
        <title>{artist.screenName}</title>
      </Head>
      <div className={styles.artistPage}>
        <ArtistHeader artist={artist} />
        <div className={styles.songContainer}>
          <UploadButton />
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}
```

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: you should consider adding a loading state ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `optional chaining`. This will prevent you from getting `undefined` error.

see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

On the other hand you can do the following:

```
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false)
const [isError, setIsError] = useState(false)

const fetchArtist = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true)
    const artistRef = doc(db, "users", `${artistId}`);
    
    try{
      const docSnap = await getDoc(artistRef);
      setArtist(docSnap.data());
    }catch(e){
      setIsError(true)
    }
    
    setIsLoading(false)
};

if(isLoading && !artist){
  return (
    <h2>Loading...</h2>
  )
}

if(!isLoading && isError){
  return (
    <h2>Something went wrong</h2>
  )
}


return (
    <section className={styles.wrapper}>
      <Head>
        <title>{artist?.screenName}</title>
      </Head>
      <div className={styles.artistPage}>
        <ArtistHeader artist={artist} />
        <div className={styles.songContainer}>
          <UploadButton />
        </div>
      </div>
     </section>
)
```

But I would prefer `react-query` for server state management. It handles all your loading | revalidation | caching and more.

Check out https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/adapters/react-query

Let's make it simple with `useQuery` hook from `react-query`

```
import { useQuery } from '@tanstack/react-query'

const fetchArtist = async (artistId: string) => {
    const artistRef = doc(db, "users", `${artistId}`);
    return getDoc(artistRef);
};

function Artist() {
  const query = useQuery(['artist', artistId], fetchArtist)

  const {isLoading, isError, data} = query 

  if(isLoading){
    return (
      <h2>Loading...</h2>
    )
  }

  if(isError && !data){
    return (
      <h2>Something went wrong</h2>
    )
  }

  return (
    <section className={styles.wrapper}>
      <Head>
        {/* optional chaining (?.) */}
        <title>{data?.artist?.screenName}</title>
      </Head>
      <div className={styles.artistPage}>
        <ArtistHeader artist={data?.artist} />
        <div className={styles.songContainer}>
          <UploadButton />
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  )
}


// _app.jsx
import { Hydrate, QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from '@tanstack/react-query'

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const [queryClient] = React.useState(() => new QueryClient())

  return (
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
      <Hydrate state={pageProps.dehydratedState}>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Hydrate>
    </QueryClientProvider>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks Adiat, are you able to provide an example of how i would apply this to my code please?

Comment: Hey, check out the solution again. I have reposted and described it brifly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getServerSideProps` to call API on the server. Whenever data is ready, the page will start loading on the client-side.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { getDoc, doc } from "firebase/firestore";
import { db } from "../api/auth/firebase/config";

import Head from "next/head";
import ArtistHeader from "../../components/ArtistHeader";
import UploadButton from "../../components/UploadButton";
import styles from "../../styles/artistPage.module.css";

export default function Artist({ data }) {
  const { data: session, status, loading } = useSession();
  const artist = data; //get data from the server
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (status === "unauthenticated") {
      router.push("/auth/signin");
    }
  }, [status, loading, router]);

  return (
    <section className={styles.wrapper}>
      <Head>
        <title>{artist.screenName}</title>
      </Head>
      <div className={styles.artistPage}>
        <ArtistHeader artist={artist} />
        <div className={styles.songContainer}>
          <UploadButton />
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const artistId = context.params.artistId; 
  const artistRef = doc(db, "users", `${artistId}`);
  const docSnap = await getDoc(artistRef);
  const data = docSnap.data();

  return { props: { data: data || null } }
}
```

Comment: It is working but i am getting an error in the terminal - error - SerializableError: Error serializing `.data` returned from `getServerSideProps` in "/artist/[artistId]".
Reason: `undefined` cannot be serialized as JSON. Please use `null` or omit this value. Any ideas how to clear this?

Comment: You can modify the return value like `return { props: { data: data || null } }`, that will help you to cover that error, @Yan. By the way, if you think my answer is useful, could you mark it as a solution for your question? That will show a little support to me as well as our community. Thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use a state isLoading. The initial value of isLoading will be false. Inside useEffect before fetching data set isLoading value as true and after completing fetching set isLoading as false. Now use conditional rendering if isLoading then render a Loader component else render jsx with data.

Comment: Thanks Arifur, Can you provide an example of how i could apply this to my code please? I played around following your advice but i would still get undefined error.